# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

I'm trying to export an excel file from a web application in Spring Framework.
First, I did it in a XLS format, that worked.
Now, I'm trying to do the same in XLSX format. To do that I changed some classes like HSSFWorkbook to XSSFWorkbook, or HSSFSheet to XSSFSheet.

The problem is in the third line of this source:

```
    XSSFCellStyle estiloFecha = workbook.createCellStyle();
    estiloFecha.cloneStyleFrom(estiloNormal);
    estiloFecha.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"));
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:754)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:399)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:354)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:185)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:159)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:108)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:193)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
```

Some help?

Comment: Looks like you have mis-matched jars. Did you [try following the instructions on the Apache POI FAQ entry on pretty much this exact topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)?

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr , I followed the instructions and now it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - you have mis-matched POI jars. Apache POI has a few different jars, covering the [different project components](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). As explained in the [POI FAQ, these *must* all be from the same version](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C)! Mixing jars between versions is not supported, and fails with errors just like this

Quick fix - remove all your Apache POI jars, and only add back the ones from the latest version.

If you can't figure out what jars you're actually using, [use the code given in this FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) to report via the classloader which jars were used. Then, remove the old ones, so you only end up with a consistent set of POI jars from one release

After that, consider using something like Apache Maven or Apache Ant or Groovy's Gradle to handle your build process and dependencies for you. Those take care of getting you a consistent set, avoiding the problems you've found with slinging random incompatible jars on your classpath!